# I am getting FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: unexpected token: StageName

Tags: batch, query

I'm writting a query in a batch like this :

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(
        'SELECT Id, StageName, Closing_Reason__c, Action_By_Date__c' +
        'FROM Opportunity' +
        'WHERE StageName = \'Imported\'' +
        'AND Action_By_Date__c < LAST_N_DAYS:60'
    );
}
```

I run the batch in an anomymous window with this code:

```
Database.executeBatch(new AutoCloseOpportunityBatch());
```

But I got error:

> FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: unexpected token: StageName
> Class.AutoCloseOpportunityBatch.start: line 2, column 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Query is missing the required spaces before FROM, WHERE and AND. You have to add the spaces as below. You can easily debug these kind of issues by using System.debug to print the Query and check if the Query is malformed.

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(
        'SELECT Id, StageName, Closing_Reason__c, Action_By_Date__c' +
        ' FROM Opportunity' +
        ' WHERE StageName = \'Imported\'' +
        ' AND Action_By_Date__c < LAST_N_DAYS:60'
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Saroj Bera! It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause is that you're missing spaces in your query string. In general, dynamic SOQL statements are far easier to get wrong, because mistakes made won't be caught until runtime, and are usually a bit harder to debug.

However, you don't need a string to execute this query. Consider using an inline query, instead:

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([
        SELECT Id, StageName, Closing_Reason__c, Action_By_Date__c
        FROM Opportunity
        WHERE StageName = 'Imported'
        AND Action_By_Date__c < LAST_N_DAYS:60
    ]);
}
```

This has the benefit of being harder to make mistakes with, because missing spaces, etc, will be caught by the compiler. You should only use dynamic SOQL if you need some sort of dynamic change (variable fields, objects, criteria, etc). This is usually not necessary for most use cases.

Comment: Thanks @sfdxfox! for sharing the valuable knowledge.